# raspberry pi + USB Hub

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, hub

I bought a cheap USB Hub Powered to connect my Raspberry Pi and two External Seagate HD (USB 2.0/3.0), but obviously that 400 mA is not enough for all this things.

So, I want to buy a new [AC Adpater](http://goo.gl/rOlHx) that supports 5V/2A.

There is a risk to combine a cheap USB Hub with 2A Adapter? 
Can I damage my Raspi if i put only it in Hub + 2A AC Adapter?

**EDIT:**

I want to connect Raspberry Pi [700mA] and Two External HD (2.0/3.0) [>500mA]. To make it possible I need a USB Adapter.
The problem was that the USB Adpater what I bought is really cheap and the AC Adapter is only 400mA (insuficient for 2 External HD).

I could buy a nice USB Hub (80 dollars), but I'm questioning myself if i could buy 2A AC Adapter (4 dollars) plus use my cheap USB Hub (5 dollars).

[image: USB Powered Hub]
[image: 2A AC Adapter]

Comment: -1 reputation? Why?

Comment: The amp rating on an adapter is the amount of current it will tolerate before either shutting down or burning up. Get the 5V/2a adapter.

Answer (score 1):

at first you have to check whether your USB hub is having current limiter or not.if there is current limiter then obviously it would limit the current, if the current drawn is exceeds the maximum rated(you mentioned it as 400mA).

there is a solution you buy a usb connector and connect that with your adapter(adapter+ with USB Vcc adapter- with USB Gnd) its better to put a current limiter along with this.

look @http://thebitbangtheory.blogspot.pt/2012/06/adding-external-power-supply-to-cheap.html

Comment: Thanks I read the article but in my case I already got a USB with power supply. I just want to "boost" 400mA to 2A without burning all my devices. Is this possible?

Comment: can you brief your requirements so that others can help you

Answer (score 1):

The Power input on the Pi is a micro USB connector, but it only uses the power traces, and not data.  The Pi needs 700 mAmps, and 1A is safer.  Many hubs will not (and should not) supply this much current.  The hub will not care about how high a current the adapter can provide, so you won't damage the hub.  You also won't damage the Raspberry Pi, but it might brown out.   With a 400mA power supply, I'd expect brownouts even if you had no disks.

Unless there's a reason to power the Pi off of a hub, you could just get a usb charger with the right connector on the end, and power directly into the Pi.

Comment: You are wrong: http://goo.gl/ljAUU

Comment: Cheap hubs don't have current limiting on the downstream ports. Or upstream port. Or at all. Often.